# Solving Laplace's Equation - weird boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

The potential is given by:

$$V = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[a_n r^n +b_nr^{-(n+1)}\right] P_n(cos \theta) $$

I want to find potential for $r \geq a$  using th definition $I_n = \int_0^1 P_n(x) \space  dx$.

The boundary conditions are:

1. $V\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$

This is easy, it simply means $a_n = 0$, so $V = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nr^{-(n+1)} P_n(cos \theta)$

2 . At r = a, for $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $, $V=1$ and for $ \frac{\pi}{2} < \theta \leq \pi $, $V=0$.

How do I even proceed?

Answer (score 2):

For $t \in (-1,1)$, let $\theta_t(x)$ be the step function

$$\theta_t(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x > t\\ \frac12,& x = t\\0,& x < t\end{cases}$$

If one expand it over $[-1,1]$ using [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), we have

$$\theta_t(x) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{2\ell+1}{2} \left( \int_{-1}^1 \theta_t(s) P_\ell(s) ds \right) P_\ell(x)
= \sum_{\ell = 0}^\infty \frac{2\ell+1}{2}
\left( \int_{t}^1 P_\ell(s) ds \right) P_\ell(x)
$$

To simplify expressions below, we will adopt the convention that $P_{-1}(x) = 1$. Under this convention, we have for any $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$(2\ell+1) P_\ell(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Big[ P_{l+1}(x) - P_{l-1}(x) \Big]$$
This leads to 
$$\int_t^1 P_{\ell}(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2\ell+1}\Big[P_{l+1}(s) - P_{l-1}(s)\Big]_t^1 = \frac{1}{2\ell+1}\Big[P_{l-1}(t) - P_{l+1}(t)\Big]$$
Substitute this back into expansion of $\theta_t(x)$, we obtain:

$$\theta_t(x) = \frac12 \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \Big(P_{\ell-1}(t) - P_{\ell+1}(t)\Big)P_\ell(x)$$

Notice when $t = 0$, we have

$$P_{\ell}(0) = \begin{cases}
1, & l = -1\\
0, & l = 2k+1\\
{\large \frac{(-1)^k (\frac12)_k}{k!}}, &l = 2k
\end{cases}
$$
where $(\gamma)_k = \gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+k-1)$ is the $k^{th}$ rising
[Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).
This give us
$$\begin{align}
\theta_0(x) 
&= \frac12 
\left[ P_{0}(x) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Big(P_{2k}(0) - P_{2k+2}(0)\Big) P_{2k+1}(x) \right]\\
&= \frac12 P_{0}(x) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\frac12)_k}{k!}\left(\frac{4k+3}{4k+4}\right) P_{2k+1}(x)\end{align}$$
At $r = a$, your potential
$$V(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{r^{n+1}} P_n(\cos\theta)$$
reduces to $\theta_0(\cos\theta)$. If one compare the coefficients for Legendre polynomials, one find
$$V(r,\theta) = \frac12 \frac{a}{r} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\frac12)_k}{k!}\left(\frac{4k+3}{4k+4}\right) \left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^{2k+2} P_{2k+1}(\cos\theta)$$

**Update**

For general $\theta$, there is no closed form expression for $V(r,\theta)$.
However, we do know what happens along the $z$-axis outside the sphere.

Let $\epsilon = \pm 1$ and $r \in [a,\infty)$. The point $p = (0,0,\epsilon r)$ lies on
the positive or negative $z$-axis depends on the sign of $\epsilon$. Notice

$$\theta(p) = \begin{cases}0,&\epsilon = +1\\ \pi,&\epsilon = -1\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\cos\theta(p) = \epsilon
\quad\implies\quad
P_{2k+1}(\cos\theta(p)) = \epsilon
$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
V(p) 
&= \frac{a}{2r} + \epsilon \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\frac12)_k}{k!}\left(\frac{4k+3}{4k+4}\right) \left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^{2k+2}\\
&= \frac{a}{2r} + \epsilon \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k 
\left[\frac{(\frac12)_k}{k!}
+ \frac12 \frac{(-\frac12)_{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
\right]\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^{2k+2}\\
&=\frac{a}{2r} + \epsilon\left[\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^2}}
- \frac12 \left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^2} - 1\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{a}{2r} + \epsilon\left[ \frac12 + \frac{a^2-r^2}{2r\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}\right]
\end{align}
$$
In particular, this recover what we expected as $r \to a_{+}$:
$$\lim_{r\to a_{+}} V(p) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = 
\begin{cases}1,& \epsilon = +1\\0,& \epsilon = -1\end{cases}$$

For an alternate treatment of this sort of potential, take a look at section $2.7$ ( and problem $2.22$ ) of J.D Jackson's classic [Classical electrodynamics, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047130932X).

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd boundary condition specifies the potential distribution on the surface r = a. This distribution of two constant values in two halves could simply be described by a step function of the angle. Then you have for this an expression to solve.

Comment: So there are two functions of potential, one between 0 and 90 deg, the other for 90 and 180 deg?

But the one for 90 to 180 deg is zero, so technically it's only between 0 and 90. In this range, cosine is between 0 and 1.

$1 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nr^{-(n+1)} P_n(cos \theta)$

If i were to times both sides by $P_n$ and integrate:
$\int_0^1 P_n dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{r^{(n+1)}} \frac{2}{2n+1}$

Comment: Still it doesn't help to solve for $b_n$

Comment: You shouldn't discard the 0~pi/2 section. You can expand the step function into Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

The second boundary condition gives,

$$ \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{b_l}{a^{l+1}} P_l(\cos(\theta)) = V(\theta) \qquad \textbf{(1)}. $$

To invert this equation for the $b_l$'s we need to exploit the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials,

$$ \int_0^\pi P_l(\cos(\theta)) P_{l'}(\cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta = \frac{2}{2l+1} \delta_{l,l'}$$

Multiplying both sides of $\textbf{(1)}$ by $P_{l'}$ and integrating from $0$ to $pi$ with respect to the measure $\sin(\theta)d\theta$ we collapse the sum on the left to just one term and are left with,

$$ \frac{2}{2l'+1}\frac{b_{l'}}{a^{l'+1}} = \int_0^\pi V(\theta) P_{l'}(\cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta  \qquad \textbf{(2)}. $$

All that is left is to evaluate the integral. I don't recall a closed form expression for this particular potential but if there is one it can probably be found using the identities in Chapter 22 of [Abromowitz and Stegun's "Handbooks of Mathematical Functions"](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/).

Comment: $\frac{2}{2l'+1}\frac{b_{l'}}{a^{l'+1}} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1 P_{l'}(\cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta  \qquad \textbf{(2)}.$

This is the form I can reduce it to at the most. I'm not sure if I can evaluate the integral

Comment: Yes that is true for your potential.

Comment: I'm a bit too tired to think it through, but I think its possible to evaluate. Is this for a homework assignment or something like that?

Comment: It's a 11 mark question on an exam paper for Electromagnetism

Comment: @user44840, an exam for which you are getting credit? In that case I am reluctant to work the problem any further.

Comment: No don't get me wrong, this was from an old paper back in 2003 for Thermal Physics (Not electromagnetism) actually. I have the link to the paper if you want.

Comment: Ok understood, the link would be appreciated. I've worked out the Legendre expansion for the unit step function which I will post as a seperate question/answer. When I've done that I'll to the link to the question in my answer here.

Comment: Thanks alot Spencer, it will definitely further my understanding about solving laplace boundary problems. The link to the paper is here:http://www27.zippyshare.com/v/49760301/file.html

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
{\rm V}\pars{r,\theta}&
=\half + \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\pars{a \over r}^{2\pars{\ell + 1}}
{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm P}_{2\ell' + 1}
> \pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> =\half + {a_{\ell'} \over 2\pars{2\ell' + 1} + 1}
> $$

$$
a_{\ell}=\pars{-2\ell - 1} - \half
+ \pars{4\ell + 3}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x
$$

> \begin{align}
> {\rm V}\pars{r,\theta}
> &=\half
> -\pars{a \over r}^{2}\color{#c00000}{\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
> \pars{2\ell + 1}\pars{a \over r}^{2\ell}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}}
> \\[3mm]&-\half\,{a \over r}\color{#00f}{\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
> \pars{a \over r}^{2\ell + 1}{\rm P}_{2\ell}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}}
> +\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
> b_{\ell}\pars{a \over r}^{2\ell + 2}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{\cos\pars{\theta}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{b_{\ell} \equiv \pars{4\ell + 3}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x}$.

Also
\begin{align}
{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}&=\sum_{\ell = 0}h^{\ell}{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{x}
\\
{1 \over \root{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}}&=\sum_{\ell = 0}h^{\ell}\pars{-1}^{\ell}
{\rm P}_{\ell}\pars{x}
\end{align}
$$
\imp\quad\color{#00f}{%
{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}
-
{1 \over \root{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}}
=2\sum_{\ell = 0}h^{2\ell + 1}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{x}}\tag{1}
$$
$$
\imp\quad\color{#c00000}{%
{h + x \over \pars{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}^{3/2}}
-
{h - x \over \pars{1 + 2xh + h^{2}}^{3/2}}
=2\sum_{\ell = 0}\pars{2\ell + 1}h^{2\ell}{\rm P}_{2\ell + 1}\pars{x}}
$$
By following the $\color{#c00000}{\tt co}\color{#00f}{\tt lors}$ we find 'closed expressions' for two terms of the solution. $\ds{b_{\ell}}$ is calculated by integrating $\pars{1}$ over $\ds{x}$ and expanding in powers of $\ds{h}$.